# Which keys may be used instead of right click button? My right click button does not work

Tags: windows

Which keys may be used instead of right click button?  My right click button does not work.

Answer (score 2):

#### Which keys may be used instead of right click button?

Some keyboards have a specific key dedicated to right click:

> [image]

Source: [How To Right-Click With The Keyboard In Windows & Mac](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/right-click-keyboard-shortcut/)

> [image]

Source: [Wicked Cool: Special Keyboard Key to Activate Right-Click Menu](https://scls.typepad.com/wicked_cool/2009/01/special-keyboard-key-to-activate-rightclick-menu.html)

If your keyboard does not have this key then:

> Luckily Windows has a universal shortcut, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, which does exactly the same thing.

Source: [How To Right-Click With The Keyboard In Windows & Mac](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/right-click-keyboard-shortcut/)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the free [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/),
you may choose any [key](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
you like.

The following script will convert <kbd>Right-Shift</kbd> to <kbd>Right-click</kbd>:

```
RShift::SendInput, {RButton}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click it
to test.
You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the traybar and
choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: What wrong with using <shift>+<f10>?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Nothing wrong, and it even doesn't need an additional installation. Just one small fault in that the position of the context menu doesn't seem to relate to the cursor.